# Dynamic timezone UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a system that user when registering a task determining the time that it should be done. By default rails works with UTC at the time, but I'd like to be changing the time zone according to the user's locale.

Anyone can help?

Comment: That's a pretty complicated question, the answer to which would go beyond the purview of SO. You might start [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones). If you have specific questions after reading some blog posts and docs, you might show some code that you've written and ask specific questions about why it isn't doing what you want it to do.

Comment: You should always work with UTC if your app is open to everyone. at the time of registering new task you can convert time in local and it will execute according to user's local timezone.

Comment: Or you can try something like this: https://github.com/kbaum/browser-timezone-rails which will take care of timezone for you.

Comment: Thank you guys, i used the gem and it worked.